# Does the Met Police Commissioner have the authority to "clean house"?

Tags: united-kingdom, police, london

The news are reporting Cressida Dick's forced resignation as the [Commissioner of Police of the Metropolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commissioner_of_Police_of_the_Metropolis) (meaning London, UK) following her preceived failure to adequately tackle racism and misogyny in the Metropolitan Police. Based on what I recall from her previous public statements, it seems not so much that she explicitly refused to do anything, on the contrary, but on occassion downplayed problems.

What I would like to understand better is whether she could have pursued a more aggresive course towards internal police reform ("cleared house"); or whether the authority of the commissioner is sufficiently limited that she might have been stuck between a rock and a hard place (ie a public demand to curtail racism and misogyny vs a police body resistant to change).

Comment: This is a bit vague. As in any organisation, there are things she could have done (not set the police on peaceful women protestors), and things she couldn't have done (sack all the police). So on a factual level the answer is yes she could have been more aggressive, but if you want to know how much she could have done, that might be a more interesting question.

Answer (score 4):

A similar situation was experienced by Sir Robert Mark, the Commissioner of the Metropolitan Police from 1972 to 77.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Mark#CID_reform):

> The Metropolitan Police had recently been rocked by exposure of
> massive corruption in the Criminal Investigation Department, and Mark,
> with the famous pronouncement, that "a good police force is one that
> catches more crooks than it employs", set about attempting to reform
> it. He changed disciplinary procedures, returned many detectives to
> uniform, made a number of television appearances praising the
> uniformed branch following student unrest and protests against the
> Vietnam War, and began to gather around him a group of loyal,
> ambitious uniformed officers who had not graduated from the old Hendon
> Police College. The uniformed branch began to gain precedence and CID
> was increasingly put under uniformed command. In 1971, with Brodie, an
> old-school officer who commanded CID, out of the country, Mark formed
> A10, a special unit established to investigate corruption.

So the Commissioner certainly had the power to successfully 'clean house' in the 1970s.  The situation was different in that the problem was mostly within the CID rather than throughout the whole organisation, but Mark made extensive reforms which lead to the dismissal of many officers.

I think Cressida Dick faced a problem with the culture across the whole of the Met, but I doubt she would have been denied the political support and administrative powers to make changes if she'd recognised that there was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little disappointed with the lack of sourcing in this [article](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2022/feb/11/how-cressida-dick-support-as-met-chief-unravelled), what are presumably a series of meetings over a number of weeks are collated into a couple of paragraphs with no more detail to review, but main point of disagreement between the Mayor's office and the commissioner appears to have been her lack of desire for a more aggressive approach.

> Dick was summoned last Wednesday to a meeting with Khan. According to a source, they spoke for 90 minutes but “she just did not get it”.

> Dick felt Khan’s demands for radical and urgent change to the Met’s culture were unwarranted and changes were in hand. The mayor made clear Dick was “on notice” – and had to do more.

It seems clear that Cressida Dick herself was opposed to significant change, and that [Sadiq Khan](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2022/feb/12/sadiq-khan-i-recall-the-bad-old-days-of-the-metropolitan-police-never-again) would not only have backed any aggressive course she was willing to peruse, but we eager to get such a plan outlined and committed to.

> I will not support the appointment of a new Commissioner unless they can clearly demonstrate that they understand the scale of the cultural problems within the Met and the urgency with which they must be addressed. In short, they need to get it, and they need to have a proper and robust plan to deal with it.

A key point to note between the two articles is the repeated use of the phrase "get it" which makes it likely the anonymous source in the first article is close to Khan.